# is it possible to create array of structures using malloc?

Tags: c

Is it possible to create array of structures using malloc ? Or one should use only a loop to create it? Any other alternate solution. Consider below program

```
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct{
        int north;
        int south;
    }   dir;

int main()
{
    dir d1[20]; // array of structures created            
    dir *s1 = malloc(sizeof(dir)); // can I create here array of structs?

    // or should i must and use loop to create array of structs?   
    dir *p1[10];
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) i[p1] = malloc(sizeof(dir));
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried goolging but did not find any useful posts. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Update**

```
dir *s1 = malloc(20 * sizeof(dir));
s1[0]->north = 20;
// error: invalid type argument of '->' (have 'dir')
```

Comment: If it wasn't possible, C wouldn't be much of a programming language, would it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done in one statement. For example

```
dir *d1 = malloc( 20 * sizeof( dir ) );
```

The syntax to access data members of a struture in the array looks like

```
d1[i].north 
d1[i].south
```

Or

```
( d1 + i )->north
( d1 + i )->south
```

Or

```
( *( d1 + i ) ).north
( *( d1 + i ) ).south
```

where i is in the range [0, 19]

Comment: The question is how do you access those array of structures?
for automatic structs such as d1 have d1[0].north and d1[1].south but *s1 is only one variable and we are creating only one pointer? right

Comment: it points to an array of structs so each entry is an individual instance of the struct

Comment: @user3205479 You asked how to create an arry of structures using maloc. I showed you how to do this.  Now you indeed can access data members of a structure in the array using syntax s1[i].north s1[i].south wgere i is in the range 0 - 0 for the example I showed.

Comment: Did I miss the introduction of the new `=>` operator?

Comment: @Jens Gustedt It is a request for feedback reative to a new C Standard proposal.:)